# How to deploy different versions of a web in different url path in Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I want to automatize the deployment of a web on Firebase hosting on each pull request in git hub with Firebase CLI. I want to deploy the version of the web of a pull request in a specific URL path.

For example, if the name of the branch of a PR is `backend/100`, I want to upload the web on `https://<project-name>.web.app/backend/100`. Then if I go to `https://<project-name>.web.app/backend/100` I can see the version of the `backend/100` branch, or If i go to `https://<project-name>.web.app/backend/180` I can see the version of the `backend/180` branch.

There is a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase supports [multiple pages per project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites). But it will look like whatever-name-you-choose.web.app (not even necessarily the same project name), say project-name-branch-name.web.app.
In terms of doing routing, "backend/100", you'd have to develop a work-around..